# Logic Level Converter, Arduino and Cellphone

Tags: arduino, cellphone, level-shifting

I am trying to interface a 6150 Nokia cellphone with an Arduino Duemilanove board, as some have already done through the **FBUS** protocol (see [here](http://www.embedtronics.com/nokia/fbus.html) for example).

The FBUS protocol uses **2.8V** logic, so I bought [Sparkfun's **logic level converter**](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/8745) to interface with the **5V** from the Arduino, right ?

[image]

They say:

> The level converter is very easy to
>   use. The board needs to be powered
>   from the two voltages sources (high
>   voltage and low voltage) that your
>   system is using. High voltage (5V for
>   example) to the 'HV' pin, low voltage
>   (2.8V for example) to 'LV', and ground
>   from the system to the 'GND' pin.

Thus

```
HV  <->  Arduino 5V
GND <->  Arduino GND

LV  <->  ??
GND <->  ??

TXI <->  Phone TX    (Low Voltage)
RXO <->  Phone RX    (Low Voltage)
TXO <->  Arduino RX  (High Voltage)
RXI <->  Arduino TX  (High Voltage)
```

The problem I have is with the low voltage source: *there is no power output on the phone.*

Can I power the converter LV/GND from another 2.8V source ? Would it be ok with the Arduino 3.3V source ?

Comment: Just brainstorming, but could you put a diode coming from the 3.3v source, hopefully dropping the voltage on the cathode side of the diode to 2.8v?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That website has a photo which shows "2-GND". This is the ground that you want to connect to the ground that you have for everything else.

As far as the 2.8v source, you can use any source you want. The voltage is just used to reference the serial signal against. If you tie it to the 3.3V it will probably work. I am not sure of the specifics of that voltage shifter, but I assume it will treat 2.8v on the signal line as being a logic high when comparing to 3.3v.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Kellenjb! If I used the Arduino for the 5V and 3.3V sources, I would thus connect the two GND to the GND of the Arduino, right ?

Comment: You need to connect the ground of the phone to your system. This is what ties the systems together to have a standard ground to reference against. If you look at the sparkfun board you will find that the grounds of both high and low are just tied together.

Comment: Do you mean `HV <-> 5V Arduino`, `HV GND <-> Arduino GND`, `LV <-> 2.8V source` and `LV GND <-> Phone GND` ? So grounds for "lows references" and power sources for "highs references".

Comment: Pretty much, yes.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a resistive [voltage divider](http://www.play-hookey.com/dc_theory/voltage_divider.html) to *create* the 2.8 Volt source from the 5 Volt supply (**HV** on the level shifter board) available from the Arduino.

[image] (image src: [Play-Hookey](http://www.play-hookey.com/dc_theory/voltage_divider.html))

Or you could use a linear voltage regulator such as the [LP3987-2.8](http://www.national.com/mpf/LP/LP3987.html#Overview) (SMT) or similar.